# Where to get additional part library graphics for BlueBrick layout designer

Tags: software, trains, vintage

I love [BlueBrick](http://bluebrick.lswproject.com/), the track and layout designer from developer  Alban Nanty. I have been using it for years and it is the best tool I have found for designing a full layout including train tracks.
However, the parts libraries available on the site do not include all sets. I am specifically interested in vintage town sets and to name just a few, the following are not included in the library:

- 6377 'Delivery Center'
- 6386 'Police Command Base'
- 6381 'Motor Speedway'
- 6389 'Fire Control Center'

Does anyone have links to BlueBrick library items for any of the missing sets, (not just the sample I listed above)?

It is possible to generate new library parts since they are made up of a gif image and an accompanying xml file, but I lack the creative ability to complete the library.

An example of a part image is shown below, (set 6394 'Metro Park & Service Tower')
[image: 6394]

Answer (score 3):

Eurobricks LEGO forum has [an index for additional Sets and Parts](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=33157) that can be added to Bluebrick. The sets that you listed above have not been recreated in Bluebrick so if you wish to use them, you need to recreate them yourself. This should be relatively easy if you find LDraw files of the sets you are looking for.

In case you wish to add new files to Bluebrick, please check the manual of Bluebrick by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> in the program. The online documentation is currently offline so I cannot directly link you to the info.